# how do disable job cancel button for each progress entry in Progress View in eclipse rcp application?

Tags: eclipse, jobs, monitor, rcp

could someone please tell me how to disable cancel button in a job's progress entry in Progress View tab in eclipse rcp application. i have not been able to locate any references on the web aside from the ones that suggest the use of ProgressMonitorDialog. using the dialog, however, is not an option, as the Progress View must remain in a form of a view.
i have come upon ProgressMonitorPart, which sounds like something that i can use. if that is the case, how do i go about passing it to Job.run(IProgressMonitor)?

thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer on what you want to achieve - do you just not want to allow your job to be cancelled?

Comment: sure, katsharp. my goal is the complete opposite. i would like to prevent users from cancelling certain jobs in mid-run. by default, each progress entry contains a progress bar followed by a red square button. i would like to disable that button, and display a tooltip text informing a user that that particular job cannot be terminated

Comment: Are these jobs your plug-in(s) have created? If they are not I do not think this is possible. Note: I am not even sure what you want to do is possible with your OWN jobs, but some workaround may be.

Comment: yes, these jobs are created directly by my code. which is why i thought about using ProgressMonitorPart somehow instead of the default IProgressMonitor.

Comment: You don't instantiate the IPM, the framework passes it to you. have you read this: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html

Comment: yes, i have seen that article before, and i do understand that it is being passed to me. i am not even sure if ProgressMonitorPart is, in fact, a part of a solution i am looking for. it was just a thought, nothing more. so at this point, i am still looking for a concrete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You can call `Job#setSystem()` on your Job so it's hinted as not to be shown, but you don't get to spin off jobs that the user can't at least *ask* you to cancel. The stop button does little more than set the progress monitor as having been canceled--it's still up to your running Job to check the progress monitor and behave itself. Or not.

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fruntime_jobs_progress.htm